# Unity 2D Error when building player for iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a problem when building the player settings in Unity, showing 3 errors (if this helps, the project is in Unity 2D):

**1.** *Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors*

**2.** *UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)*

**3.** *UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors:*

**3a.** at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002d8] in :0

**3b** *at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in :0*

**Here's what I've tried (all these didn't work):**

- Deleting the Library folder
- Changing the input manager in player settings from old to new (got errors for that so turned it back to old)
- Trying to build the project outside of the project folder itself, live in Onedrive and the desktop folder

Anyone else had this issue? If so, how did you fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the error. Previously in the console it had an error in a script, and after fixing that it completed the build. This really deserves a face palm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).